# How can I replace/extract parts of a path?

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    $path = "monkey/cat/horse";
    $linkPath = str_replace("/", "</a><br><a href='my page.html/".$path."'>", $path);
    echo "<a href='my page.html/".$path."'>".$linkPath . "</a>";
?>
```

On my page it outputs this:

```
<a href='my page.html/monkey/cat/horse'>monkey</a><br>
<a href='my page.html/monkey/cat/horse'>cat</a><br>
<a href='my page.html/monkey/cat/horse'>horse</a>
```

Now my problem is that if want the link to be only the path of the value. This means my desired result should be instead

```
<a href='my page.html/monkey'>monkey</a><br>
<a href='my page.html/monkey/cat'>cat</a><br>
<a href='my page.html/monkey/cat/horse'>horse</a>
```

Comment: edit your question to make the code look sane (`$path`) and add your current code that produces `My result`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I marked the code that produces the output with `This is my code` and what do you mean by "sane"?

Comment: so you want 3 links from one string or what?

Comment: Sorry, forgot `""`

Comment: like categories and each level deeper separately?

Comment: Well, if I a have some path like `something/somethingelse/cheese/something/somethingnew/tomato` and if I click on for example `cheese` I need the output `something/somethingelse/cheese` Is this possible?

Comment: Yes like a breadcump trail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace()` is not the right way to go.

```
$path = "monkey/cat/horse";

$level = '';
foreach(explode('/', $path) as $segment) {
   $level .= "/{$segment}";
   echo "<a href='my page.html{$level}'>{$segment}</a>";
}
```

would echo

```
<a href='my page.html/monkey'>monkey</a>
<a href='my page.html/monkey/cat'>cat</a>
<a href='my page.html/monkey/cat/horse'>horse</a>
```

**EDIT**

> is it possible to make the last segment not as a link

Yes it is, but you should try yourself first...

```
$level = '';
$tmp = explode('/', $path);
$count = count($tmp);
for($i=0; $i<($count-1); $i++) {
   $segment = $tmp[$i];
   $level .= "/{$tmp[$i]}";
   echo "<a href='my page.html{$level}'>{$tmp[$i]}</a>";
}
echo $tmp[$count-1];
```

Comment: One last question, is it possible to make the last segment not as a link? In this case `horse`?

Comment: See edited answer. But note SO is not "write me code" site

Comment: Thank you very much! I just didn't know if it is possible with your solution.